# Chinese encoding in jsp and java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, character-encoding

suppose some Chinese text is there in an xml. I want to display the same chinese text in jsp.

What would be the better way to do this.
Do i need to encode the whole xml.
Do i encode in the java and jsp.

Is this better to encode while setting in the java or displaying in the jsp.

Comment: Did you try it yet? Show your code.

Comment: Follow this link...bottomline you need to make sure you use UTF8 encoding at java as well as html where you want to display chinese character http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1030399

Answer (score 0):

First: there is no problem.

For international sites Unicode is often the preferred choice, as it can combine all possible scripts on one page (if the fonts can display them).

For a Chinese-only site, say combined with plain ASCII, you can display the page in a Chinese encoding.

Now the XML can be in UTF-8, a Unicode formatting, using multiple bytes for Chinese. For Chinese another encoding might be more compact, but the ASCII tags in XML and HTML make UTF-8 still sufficient efficient.

Java internally holds Strings as chars in Unicode (UTF-16 actually), so there is no problem too.

Only the output encoding of the JSP needs a choice. The JSP itself can also be in UTF-8 with hard-coded Chinese strings, and still specify another encoding.

The following would be for Mainland China, resp. Taiwan/Hong Kong/Macau.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=GB18030" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=Big5" %>
```

Check that the installed java has the charset.

Answer (score -1):

use dom4j and reload xml file;

```
org.dom4j.io.SAXReader reader=new SAXReader();
org.dom4j.Document doc=reader.read(new File(yourFilePath));
org.dom4j.io.OutputFormat format=new OutputFormat();
format.setEncoding("utf-8");
org.dom4j.io.XMLWriter writer=new XMLWriter(new FileOutputStream(path),format);  
writer.write(doc);
writer.close();
```